# Win phone 10 - Accessing directory and moving files

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2015

I have created an simple app to compress pictures for my Windows phone 10. However I dont now how to access directory with pictures.

Is there same folder hierarchy as in PC Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to access directories such as Pictures or Documents for a current user from an UWP app, you should use:

(Picture library in this case)

```
 Windows.Storage.StorageLibrary.GetLibraryAsync
    (Windows.Storage.KnownLibraryId.Pictures);
```

[msdn article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-managing-folders-in-the-music-pictures-and-videos-libraries)

Comment: Thank you. Is there possibility to access those directories in a "PC" way? I am not really into changing my whole compress library

Comment: What do you mean? do you want to open a dialog window for the user, where he can select a file to compress? What does it mean "PC" way? Do you need the user to specify a path to the file he wants to compress? Or do you need to find out where is it you can store the compressed file?

Comment: I just wanted to set directory path from root, set some directory for temporary files and so on. However I have problem working with bitmaps anyway